# Create Function for output in Shiny

Tags: r, function, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a question about the Output Function in a Shiny application. Is it possible to write an output function with a variable as name to use it multiple times?

For example a short extract:

```
  output$MainBody <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      gradientBox(
        title = "Test",
      )
    )
  })
```

Is it possible to use a function like this:

```
dt_representation <- function(x){
      output$x <- renderUI({
        fluidPage(
          gradientBox(
            title = "Test",
          )
        )
      })
}
```

And call this funcion with:

```
dt_representation(MainBody)
```

Is that a possibility, or doesn't that work in Shiny?

Comment: I think modules functionality is what you need, have a read 
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **strongly recommand** to use modules as [Pork Chop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2753526/pork-chop) said.
But it can happen sometime I use such a little "hack" :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   uiOutput("all_id")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    # Define function
    createUI <- function(x, text) {
        output[[x]] <<- renderUI({
            div(text)
        })
    }

    # Use function
    createUI("id1", "Here is my first UI")
    createUI("id2", "Here is my second UI")

    # Combine all in one
    output$all_id <- renderUI({
        do.call(fluidRow, lapply(c("id1","id2"), uiOutput))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```